# вылет интерфейса системы при toast

Tags: java, android, toast

я попробовал добавить toast и привязать его к кнопке

```
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "VOID", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();
            }
        });
```

но при нажатии на кнопку сначала ничего не происходит, а потом появляется диалоговое окно ,которое сообщает о том, что "интерфес системы" не отвечает

Comment: В самом toast ничего криминального нет, скорее всего проблема где-то в другом месте.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja это может быть связвано с использованием Android 13 (API 33) на тестовом устройстве?

Comment: Скорее всего вы просто где-то блокируете main thread.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja как это можно исправить? я проверил приложение на версии андроид 10 и все работает без краша системы.

Comment: ANR это не краш, возможно просто совпадение на Андроид 13. Вот тут подсказки как искать проблему. https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/vitals/anr

Comment: Покажите весь код